# CollapsingTolbar work with fagment contain SwipeRefreshLayout and RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, swiperefreshlayout

Hi I'm Working on `CollapsingToobar` and a `Framelayout`. a `Fragment` will replace the `FrameLayout` when there is `transaction`. A `fragment` contain `SwipeRefreshLayout` and a `RecycleView` inside. But whenever I put the `swipeRefreshLayout`, `RecycleView` does not appear (it function normally without `SwipeRefreshLayout`).

Here is my xml for the activity `activity_topstory_detail`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".TopStoryDetailActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/topStory_detail_nested_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/topStory_detail_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My layout for fragment `TopStoryDetailFragment`

```
<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/topStory_detail"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    tools:context=".TopStoryDetailFragment">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <include layout="@layout/comment_list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my `comment_list` layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/comment_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/comment_list_content"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any way to make `SwipeRefreshLayout`, `RecycleView` and `CollapsingToolbar` working together? any help is much appreciate. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an app I am currently working on I got an Layout Working with SwipeRefreshLayout, RecyclerView and CollpasingToolbar.

This is the Main Layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/coordinator">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/appList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
           />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemIconTint="#2196f3"
        app:itemTextColor="#009688"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the Collapsing Toolbar Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/MyAppbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_500"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:transitionName="@string/transition_app_icon"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Maybe it helps

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for your help. I am working with a fragment that contain swipeRefreshLayout and recycle view. Find out that put swipeRefreshLayout in the main activity and nestedscroll view inside, a FrameLayout inside nested scroll view. Make fragment transaction for frameview. Call parent layout swipeRefreshLayout when in fragment make it work. Don't know whether it is this a good approach

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use SwipeRefreshLayout, RecycleView and CollapsingToolbar . I look into your code , problem is you are using NestedScrollView with recyclerview. **Just remove the NestedScrollview**

Comment: Think we need to keep the nestedscroll view otherwise collapsing toolbar will not work properly

Comment: I think to solve issue must to remove the scrollview, collapibletoolbar toolbar will work, if not , your can manage programatically

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who need fragment to work with Collapsing toolbar, SwipeRefreshLayout, RecycleView. I find myself a way that put SwipeRefreshLayout on the main activity, a nestedScrollView inside, a FrameLayout inside nested ScrollView. In fragment OnCreatedView, call the activity swipeRefreshLayout. Dont know whether it is a good approach but it work

my activity layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".TopStoryDetailActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/topStory_detail_nested_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/topStory_detail_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

my fragment layout

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/topStory_detail"
style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
tools:context=".TopStoryDetailFragment">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<include layout="@layout/comment_list" />
```

my comment_list layout

```
<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/comment_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/comment_list_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I call the swipeRefreshLayout by

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.topstory_detail, container, false);

        // Lookup the swipe container view
        swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
```